# How to increase Logistic Regression score on Sklearn PCA?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, pca

I want to make a comparison between Lenet and PCA on regards to image recognition, so I used the German Traffic Signals Benchmark and the Sklearn PCA module, but when I tested it using Logistic Regression, the score didn't get higher than 6%, no matter what i tried.

I tried modifying the number of interations and the number of preprocesses (using normalizations and equalization), but it still didn't work

The files are loaded by Pickle by three archives:

```
train.p, with shape of (34799, 32, 32, 3)
test.p, with shape of (12630, 32, 32, 3)
valid.p, with shape of (4410, 32, 32, 3)
```

each of them with its labels, as written in y_train, y_test and y_valid.
and this is the relevant part of the code:

```
def gray_scale(image):
    """
    Convert images to gray scale.
        Parameters:
            image: An np.array compatible with plt.imshow.
    """
    return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

def preprocess2(data):

    n_training = data.shape
    gray_images = np.zeros((n_training[0], n_training[1], n_training[2]))
    for i, img in enumerate(data):
        gray_images[i] = gray_scale(img)
    gray_images = gray_images[..., None]
    return gray_images

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

pca = PCA(0.95)

X_train_preprocess = preprocess2(X_train)
#Removing one dimension (34799,32,32,1) to (34799,32,32)
X_train_preprocess = X_train_preprocess.reshape(34799,32,32)
nsamples, nx, ny = X_train_preprocess.shape
X_train_preprocess = X_train_preprocess.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))

X_test_preprocess = preprocess2(X_test)
#Removing one dimension (34799,32,32,1) to (12630,32,32)
X_test_preprocess = X_test_preprocess.reshape(12630,32,32) 
n2samples, n2x, n2y = X_test_preprocess.shape
X_test_preprocess = X_test_preprocess.reshape((n2samples,n2x*n2y))

print(X_train_preprocess.shape)
pca.fit(X_train_preprocess)
print(pca.n_components_)
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train_preprocess)
X_t_train = scaler.transform(X_train_preprocess)
X_t_test = scaler.transform(X_test_preprocess)

X_t_train = pca.transform(X_t_train)
X_t_test = pca.transform(X_t_test)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logisticRegr = LogisticRegression(solver = 'lbfgs', max_iter = 5000)
logisticRegr.fit(X_t_train, y_train)
print('score', logisticRegr.predict(X_t_test[0:10]))
print('score', logisticRegr.score(X_t_test, y_test))
```

The results were these:

```
(34799, 1024)
62
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py:469: FutureWarning: Default multi_class will be changed to 'auto' in 0.22. Specify the multi_class option to silence this warning.
  "this warning.", FutureWarning)
score [ 1  2 10 10 13 10 25  1  1  4]
score 0.028820269200316707
```

So I want to see if you guys can enlighten me on what am I doing wrong and what can I do to make this work properly

Comment: It would help extremely if you could link to the dataset.  As is, your code stands as not being reproducible in results.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can edit the post, but here it is the complete set of images: [link](http://benchmark.ini.rub.de/?section=gtsrb&subsection=dataset), and the images were put together on .p files in here: [link](https://github.com/mohamedameen93/German-Traffic-Sign-Classification-Using-TensorFlow)

Comment: You can always edit your post. It's at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

you got 2d data in image recognition ， it's best to use cnn network to present the relation in high dimension

related link :[Training CNN with images in sklearn neural net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506358/training-cnn-with-images-in-sklearn-neural-net)

Comment: You're missing the point. He wants to compare performance with PCA. He's already aware of CNNs.